# Issues with one-sided one-to-one relationships and cascading delete in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My overall data structure is:

```
Story
|— VotesPool
|  \— Votes[]
|— ShelfStoriers[]
|— StoryTags[]
\— Chapters[]
   \— CommentsThread
      \— Comments[]
```

Deleting is done with simple `_context.Stories.Remove(Story)`, nothing fancy

When a `Story` gets deleted, `Chapter`s do too, so do `StoryTags`s and `ShelfStory`s, but nothing more from this structure, including the dependents of `Chapter`. The database is filled with orphans.

What those two leftovers (`Story.VotesPool` and `Chapter.CommentsThread`) have in common, is that they're both a one-to-one relationship where the reference is kept only on the parent, e.g.

```cs
class Story {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public VotesPool Votes {get;set;}
}
class Comment {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public VotesPool Votes {get;set;}
}
class VotesPool {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<Vote> Votes {get;set;}
}
```

Instead of what is, I suppose, the proper way to set it up:

```cs
class Story {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public VotesPool Votes {get;set;}
}
class Comment {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public VotesPool Votes {get;set;}
}
class VotesPool {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<Vote> Votes {get;set;}
  public Story? Story {get;set;}
  public Comment? Comment {get;set}
}
```

but this solution doesn't sit well with me for two reasons:

1. Both `VotesPool` and `CommentsThread` are sort of transient, join tables, they're not immediately relevant. Thus, referencing parents there seems a bit pointless
2. Using this solution would create the necessity of updating `VotesPool` and `CommentsThread` model each time I decide to attach them to some new model. If I wanted to add `CommentsThread` to `Story`, I would have to add `Story` to `CommentsThread` as well

[Here's](https://github.com/Atulin/Ogma/blob/master/Ogma3/Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs) my DbContext config where all the delete behaviors are (supposedly) set up. The rest of the code is in that repo as well. I'm using EF Core and PostgreSQL.

Is the way my data is modeled, that is the one-sided relationships the crux of the issue here? Should it be fixed by making the relationship two-sided, or is there some annotation/fluent method of handling it without changing the models themselves?